# Help to prove that $|(s − i)(s − i − 1)| ≤ 1/4$, with $s \in \mathbb{R}; s \in (0,n)$; $i, n \in \mathbb{N}$; and $i$ such that $i<s<i+1$,

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $s$ is a real number such that $s \in (0,n)$, with $n$ some integeer, and $i$ is another integeer such that $i<s<i+1, \forall s\in (0,n)$, how could be proven that $|(s − i)(s − i − 1)| ≤ 1/4$?

Comment: With  $x = s-i$ your expression is $x(1-x)$ ...

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that $|ab| \leq \left( \frac{|a|+|b|} {2} \right)^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. Has that inequality any special name?

Comment: Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean. It's applied to non-negative reals, hence the absolute values.